# Command or alias in echo command (Linux Ubuntu Bash)

Tags: linux, bash, alias

I made a permanent alias called usernum that looks like this:

```
usernum='who | wc -l'
```

It simply returns how many users there are.
I'm trying to put the following command in a cronjob.

```
echo "The following number of users are logged in: $usernum"
```

However, this only echos:

```
The following number of users are logged in:
```

How do I make it so that a command can be used in the string of an echo command with substitution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change to:

```
alias usernum='who | wc -l'
echo "The following number of users are logged in: $(usernum)"
The following number of users are logged in: 1
```

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I was looking for. I'm really new to Linux and I couldn't find this simple answer for some reason.

Comment: @chepner I have added the actual commands and output to show that it works.

Comment: Sorry, I failed to notice you defined an actual alias.

Answer (score 3):

Use a function instead of an alias:

```
usernum() { who | wc -l ; }
```

Then call the function:

```
echo "$(usernum) users are logged in."
```